# Elements added to collection should be objects. Why can I add a primitive data type then?

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.*;
       class Ball{
         public static void main(String args[])
         {
            ArrayList <Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            al.add(new Integer(1));
            System.out.println(al);
            }   
         }
```

I was reading The complete reference Java 2 by Herbert Schildt and I came across this snippet.
It said

```
The program begins by creating a collection of integers.
```

`You cannot store primitive data types in a collection`

```
 so objects of type Integer are created and stored.
```

However I tried using `al.add(1)` and it works. How? (In this case 1 is a primitive data type and NOT an object)

Comment: Because 1 is boxed to Integer. If you were using Java < 5, it wouldn't compile. You can read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

Your primitive values will be boxed to appropriate wrapper objects (Integer, Long etc) and added to Collection, and this feature added from java 5.

If you use older version(before Java 5), you will get compilation error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`1` is autoboxed; the compiler takes care of that for you. What happens is that at runtime your add really is:

```
al.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Note that `Integer`s are tricky to *remove* from `List`s, since you have *two* remove methods: one removing an element at a given index (`.remove(int)`) and one removing an object in the list (`.remove(T)`).

So, if you want to remove *object* `1` from your list you'll have to `.remove(Integer.valueOf(1))`...

Comment: al.remove(0) removes the element from positon 0.

Comment: @user3442084 yes, it does; however, if you had an _`Integer`_ 0 to remove from the list you'd have to `.remove(Integer.valueOf(0))`.

Comment: `add` is also running `Integer.valueOf(1)` instead of `new Integer(1)`. Please, fix it